# Unable to hide the tr elements on button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two buttons: `#btn1` and `#btn2` and two table rows: `#tr1` and `#tr2`. I am setting the buttons to active when the user clicks on the button.

My requirements are:

- when the button is `active` I need to show the elements in the `tr`.
- when the button is `inactive` I need to hide the `tr` elements.

How can I do this?

Jquery code for enabling the button:

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
});
$("#btn2").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
});
```

html code:

```
<tr id="tr1">
    <td><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr2">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="val3" id="val3"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, I need to hide tr1 if btn1 is not active and show tr1 only if btn1 is active, same for btn2.

Comment: What `tr` elements? If you have two buttons, should the `tr` be hidden if any one of them is 'disabled'? We need much clearer information.

Comment: Also note that the styles of the buttons don't change in the UI as you retain the `.buttonInactive` class in all states, and that overrides `.buttonActive`

Comment: Instead of toggling the class on the button, toggle the class on the container and use css

Comment: yes i have two buttons first time when user lands into the page the buttons are displayed as inactive when user clicks on the button it becomes active so when button is inactive i need to hide tr elements how to do this

Comment: but how can i do this i am trying to achieve this by using below code but its not working 
$("#btn1").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
        $('.tr1').toggle();
    });

Comment: change `$('.tr1').toggle();` to `$('#tr1').toggle();`

Comment: Again, if you had put that code in the question up-front, it would have a) been clearer what you are trying to achieve and b) been quick to see what the issue you were having was.     Given the number of views and comments shows people want to help you, so don't be discouraged, just include all the info you need answering and what you've tried.

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

**you want to add below two line in both button click events.**

```
$("#tr1").toggle();
$("#tr2").toggle();
```

Your jQuery code here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tr1").hide();
    $("#tr2").hide();
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
    $("#tr1").show();
    $("#tr2").hide();
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
    $("#tr1").hide();
    $("#tr2").show();
  });
});
```

**If you have want to all tr elements show/hide. You just add one line below**

```
$("tr").toggle();
```

Comment: that is not my question tr1 is related to btn1 click event and tr2 is related to btn2 click event and below is my jquery code in click function i am making btn1 and btn2 as actives if user clicks
and i am making disable when again he clicks my requirement is when inactive i need to hide tr elements
 $("#btn1").click(function () {
        debugger;
        $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
        $('.trworkstatus').toggle();
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function () {
        debugger;
        $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
        $('.trmemberinfo').toggle();
    });

Comment: **By default both tr elements are disabled. If when you have want to click on btn1 then after tr1 element show and tr2 element hide same vice versa for btn2. Please see below code.**

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $("#tr1").hide();
    $("#tr2").hide();

    $("#btn1").click(function () { 
        $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
        $("#tr1").show();
        $("#tr2").hide();
    }); $("#btn2").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
        $("#tr1").hide();
        $("#tr2").show();
    });

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to change css and jquery below, check it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tr1').hide();
  $('#tr2').hide();
  $('#tr3').hide();
});

$("#btn1").click(function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
         if($(this).hasClass("buttonActive")){
           $('#tr1').show();
         }
         else{
           $('#tr1').hide();
         }
    });
$("#btn2").click(function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
         $('#tr2').show();
         if($(this).hasClass("buttonActive")){
           $('#tr2').show();
         }
         else{
           $('#tr2').hide();
         }
    });
$("#btn3").click(function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
         $('#tr3').show();
         if($(this).hasClass("buttonActive")){
           $('#tr3').show();
         }
         else{
           $('#tr3').hide();
         }
    });
```

```css
.buttonInactive {
    background-color: #1E78AB;
    border: 1px solid #1E78AB;
    color: #fff;

}
.buttonInactive.buttonActive {
    background-color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #1E78AB;
    color: #1E78AB;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="buttonInactive">Btn1</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" class="buttonInactive">Btn2</button>
<button id="btn3" type="button" class="buttonInactive">Btn3</button>




<table>
  <tr id="tr1">
  <td>
  <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" placeholder="val1"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2" placeholder="val2"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
  <td>
  <input type="text" name="val3" id="val3" placeholder="val3"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="val4" id="val4" placeholder="val4"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
  <td>
  <input type="text" name="val5" id="val5" placeholder="val5"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="val6" id="val6" placeholder="val6"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Hiren Vaghasiya can you please show the example by adding one more tr and one more button in additional to the existing logic